# Pagination link is not working - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have a problem with the wordpress homepage, special offers pagination does not work, follow the link and code.

If you click pag 2 products listed are the same.

[Link](http://deliosbar.com.br)

```
function atpmenutypepagination($range =2,$pages = '') { 

    global $paged,$wp_query;
    $out='';
    $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;       
    if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;
    if($pages == ''){
        $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
        if(!$pages){
            $pages = 1; 
        }     
    }   

    //if pages more than one
    if(1 != $pages){
        $out.='<div class="pagination wp-pagenavi">
                <span class="pages extend">
                    Pag '.$paged.'  de  '.$pages.
                '</span>';
        if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) $out.='<a href="'.get_pagenum_link(1).'">&laquo;</a>';
        if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) $out.='<a href="'.get_pagenum_link($paged - 1).'">&lsaquo;</a>';
        for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++){
            if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))  {
                $out.=($paged == $i)? '<span class="current">'.$i.'</span>':'<a href="'.get_pagenum_link($i).'" class="inactive" >'.$i.'</a>';
            }
        }

        if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) $out.='<a href="'.get_pagenum_link($paged + 1).'">&rsaquo;</a>';  
        if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) $out.='<a href="'.get_pagenum_link($pages).'">&raquo;</a>';
        $out.= '</div>';
    }
    return $out;
}//end of function atpmenutypepagination
```

Comment: Why did you link to an under construction page?

Comment: Can now access, remove your temporary files. Thank you.